# How to access and see Liferay

Tags: mysql, database, ssh, liferay

How can I see/access Liferay Database? I want to see all the tables its using. Does a regular Liferay or Tomcat Installation include a software like PhpMyAdmin to administer?

Some additional information:
The Liferay I'm trying to access is sitting on Amazon EC2 And I can use terminal command using SSH.

Comment: Which version of Liferay are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just unziped liferay and started it than your database is simply a file '[instalation_directory]/data/hsql/lportal.script'. Which you can open with any text editor.

Or you can stop liferay and take a look at [this](http://www.programmingforfuture.com/2010/06/using-hypersql-hsqldb.html)

Comment: Hi Martin thanks! I have accessed the portal.script but it seem its not structured as a table the way I'm expecting. The second solution is something what i'm looking but setting it up confuses me.

Comment: This is because that file is just a stor for HSQL database. You should use some sort of database tool to see what you want. Which do you use?

Comment: when viewing it I used just a text-editor(panic coda). For Database tool I'm not sure what to use. I'm use viewing my database inside PhpMyAdmin. but that was in a PHP environment. I'm not sure with Java/Liferay.

Comment: Can you recommend a tool that you think It can help me?

Answer (score 1):

Ok first when you download Liferay bundle, it comes with Hypersonic database. This should only be used for demo purpose. What we normally do is replace Hypersonic with enterprise database like MySQL. The steps to do the same is mentioned here. http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Database+Configuration

In short download mysql. Create a database in mysql and specify the jdbc properties for that db in portal-ext.properties as mentioned in above link.

Once you have that i think you can use phpAdmin or any MYSQL Query browser(I use [SQLYOG](http://code.google.com/p/sqlyog/)) to point to this database and see the values.

Answer (score 0):

The database that liferay connects to will be configured using `portal-ext.properties`. You can find this file under:

```
<liferay-root>/<tomcat>/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes
```

Comment: Hi Adarshr, Thank you for your answer. 

here's what I saw in portal-ext.properties.

# Database settings
jdbc.default.jndi.name=jdbc/LiferayPool

I'm not sure how to use this or access this.

Comment: Which app server are you using? If it's tomcat, the actual configuration for `jdbc/LiferayPool` will be defined inside `<tomcat>/conf/server.xml` under the tag `<Resource auth="Container" driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" name="jdbc/LiferayPool" type="javax.sql.DataSource" url="jdbc:oracle:thin:..........................."/>`

Comment: Here's what I have:

    <Resource auth="Container" description="User database that can be updated and saved" factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory" name="UserDatabase" pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"/>
  </GlobalNamingResources>